# Can not connect to socket in xmpp in swift 3

Tags: swift, xmpp

I am trying to connect xmpp stream socket but can not connect. I am using swift 3. Its working in Objcetiv-C and swift 2.0 but not working in swift 3. Please review my following code and please help me. Thanks.

```
func setupStream()
{
    xmppStreamChat = XMPPStream.init()

    xmppReconnect = XMPPReconnect()
    //xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.init()
    xmppRoster = XMPPRoster.init(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage)
    xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;

    xmppStreamChat.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppRoster.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

    xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;

    xmppvCardStorage = XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
    xmppvCardTempModule = XMPPvCardTempModule.init(vCardStorage: xmppvCardStorage)

    xmppvCardAvatarModule = XMPPvCardAvatarModule.init(vCardTempModule: xmppvCardTempModule)
    xmppCapabilitiesStorage = XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
    xmppCapabilities = XMPPCapabilities.init(capabilitiesStorage: xmppCapabilitiesStorage);
    xmppCapabilities.autoFetchHashedCapabilities = true;
    xmppCapabilities.autoFetchNonHashedCapabilities = false;
    xmppReconnect.activate(xmppStreamChat)
    xmppRoster.activate(xmppStreamChat)

    xmppvCardTempModule.activate(xmppStreamChat)
    xmppvCardAvatarModule.activate(xmppStreamChat)
    xmppCapabilities.activate(xmppStreamChat)


    xmppStreamChat.hostName = "95.138.180.254"
    xmppStreamChat.hostPort = 5222
}

func connect() -> Bool
{
    if !((xmppStreamChat.isConnected()))
    {
        let jabberID = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "XMPPUserName") as! String) + "@95.138.180.254"
        let myPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "XMPPPassword")

        if !((xmppStreamChat.isDisconnected()))
        {
            return true
        }

        if jabberID.length == 0 && myPassword?.length == 0
        {
            return false
        }
        xmppStreamChat.myJID = XMPPJID.init(string: jabberID)
        do {
            try xmppStreamChat.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
            print(xmppStreamChat.isConnecting()) // This prints true
            //try xmppStreamChat.connect(to: xmppStreamChat.myJID, withAddress: nil, withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
            print("Connection success")
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong!")
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, socketDidConnect socket: GCDAsyncSocket)
This method is getting called but after that no any delegate method is calling. Please help if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

make singleton of that class as follows:

```
class XMPPController: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = XMPPController();
```

your set up method:

```
    func setupStream()
    {
    /***set up code goes here***/
    }
```

Now your connect method:

```
func connect() -> Bool{
    /***connect code goes here***/
    }
```

now call it in another controller as follows:

```
    func testConnect() {
            XMPPController.sharedInstance.setupStream();
            XMPPController.sharedInstance.connect();
    }
```